# UFW - Allow SSH in custom port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, firewall, ufw

[image]

I'm new to ufw, and followed this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04) and entered exact command as instructed.

```
ufw allow ssh 2222
```

Since my SSH is 2222, I want to add that rule in, but I kept getting

> ERROR: Need 'to' or 'from' clause

Any hints for me ? I don't want to get lock out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67232452/1030675

Comment: I closed the other one. sorry. migrating, and didn't delete fast enough.

Comment: sudo allow 2222

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ufw man says:

> Example rules using the simple syntax:
>
> ```
>      ufw allow 53
> ```
>
> This rule will allow tcp and udp port 53 to any address on  this  host.
> To specify a protocol, append '/protocol' to the port. For example:
>
> ```
>      ufw allow 25/tcp
> ```
>
> This  will allow tcp port 25 to any address on this host. ufw will also
> check /etc/services for the port and protocol if specifying  a  service
> by name.  Eg:
>
> ```
>      ufw allow smtp
> ```

So if you say

```
ufw allow ssh
```

it is the equivalent of

```
ufw allow 22/tcp
```

In your case it would work if you put just

```
ufw allow 2222
```

or

```
ufw allow 2222/tcp
```

since I guess you don't need udp...